# Remove all text between a <p> tag

Tags: objective-c, regex, string

I have a `<p>` tag that looks like this:

```
<p class=\"padding-top\" style=\"padding:0;margin:0 0 1em;line-height:1.35;padding-top:18px\">
```

I want to know what's the regex to remove the content between this tag. I tried `<p([^>]+)>([^>]+)</p>`

but it won't work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to remove all the attributes of your `<p>`, which is probably stored in a NSString?

Comment: No, I have this p tag and I want to remove all the content in it.

Comment: You really, really, really shouldn't use regex to match HTML/XML. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags